# System.Net.WebClient in asp.net vnext for dnx core 5.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I installed the RC for asp.net vnext, but I can't seem to find the `webclient`.

Saw blogposts that it should be in 
`"System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516"` or in `"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3"` but I didn't find it...

In which place should I look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should learn how to live without it, as it is not part of CoreFX (at least for now),

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?q=webclient&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Time to move to `HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: Ok, will try the `HttpWebRequest`. The `HttpClient` keeps ginving me erros when I search for the nuget package which contains it.

Comment: @Michel do you know that you need to modify project.json? In that file you need to add System.Net.Http as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It should be build on top of System.Net.Http in 1.2.0 version https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11794